# Por que só funciona da forma esperada da segunda vez?

Tags: javascript, canvas, for

Eu tenho essa função:

```
for (var i in chars) {
        chars[i].walk();
        for (var j in chars) {
            if (i != j) {
                collision(chars[i], chars[j]);
                action(chars[i], chars[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Ela funciona de uma forma inesperada quando eu chamo pela primeira vez, somente quando eu chamo ela pela segunda vez de forma seguida ela funciona? (não funciona se eu chamar ela e depois outra e depois chamar ela de novo).

`chars` é um array que guarda ojetos da classe `Character`.

`collision` funciona corretamente e eu tentei tirar ela e não alterou em nada.

Função `walk`:

```
walk () {
    if (!this.acting && this.walking) {
        switch (this.walking) {
            case "left":
                this.animate(9, 9);
                this.posX -= this.speed;
                break;
            case "right":
                this.animate(11, 9);
                this.posX += this.speed;
                break;
            case "up":
                this.animate(8, 9);
                this.posY -= this.speed;
                break;
            case "down":
                this.animate(10, 9);
                this.posY += this.speed;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Os arquivos completos são esses:

1. `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Undivine</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas height="600" id="canvas" width="800"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="js/load.js" onload="loadJS('js/message', 'js/character', 'js/collision', 'js/script')"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

2. `css/styles.css`:

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa+Slab+One";
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    text-align: center;
}
#canvas {
    background-color: #f00;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

3. `js/character.js`:

```js
class Character {
    constructor (img, posX, posY, visible) {
        //propriedades
        this.acting = null;
        this.height = 64;
        this.img = img;
        this.posX = posX;
        this.posY = posY;
        this.speed = 3;
        this.srcX = 0;
        this.srcY = 10;
        this.step = 0;
        this.visible = visible;
        this.walking = null;
        this.width = 64;
    }
    //metodos
    action () {
        if (this.acting) {
            switch (this.acting) {
                case "spellcast":
                    var cols = 7;
                    var srcY = 0 + this.srcY % 4;
                    break;
                case "thrust":
                    var cols = 8;
                    var srcY = 4 + this.srcY % 4;                   
                    break;
                case "slash":
                    var cols = 6;
                    var srcY = 12 + this.srcY % 4;                  
                    break;
                case "shoot":
                    var cols = 13;
                    var srcY = 16 + this.srcY % 4;                  
                    break;
                case "hurt":
                    var cols = 6;
                    var srcY = 20;                  
                    break;
            }
            if (this.animate(srcY, cols)) {
                var acting = this.acting;
                this.acting = null;
                this.step = 0;
                if (acting != "hurt") {
                    this.srcX = 0;
                }
                return acting;
            }
        }
    }
    animate (srcY, cols) {
        if (this.srcY == srcY) {
            this.srcX = Math.floor(this.step / 5) % cols;
            this.step++;
            return this.step == cols * 5 - 1;
        } else {
            this.srcY = srcY;
            this.step = 0;
        }
    }
    bottomEdge () {
        return this.posY + this.height;
    }
    centerX () {
        return this.posX + this.width / 2;
    }
    centerY () {
        return this.posY + this.height / 2;
    }
    cursor (e) {
        return e.offsetX >= this.posX && e.offsetX < this.rightEdge() && e.offsetY >= this.posY && e.offsetY < this.bottomEdge()?true:false;
    }
    direction () {
        switch (this.srcY % 4) {
            case 0:
                return "up";
                break;
            case 1:
                return "left";
                break;
            case 2:
                return "down";
                break;
            case 3:
                return "right";
                break;
        }
    }
    draw (cnv, ctx) {
        if (this.visible) { 
            switch (this.posX) {
                case "center":
                    this.posX = (cnv.width - this.width) / 2;
                    break;
                case "left":
                    this.posX = 0;
                    break;
                case "right":
                    this.posX = cnv.width - this.width;
                    break;
            }
            switch (this.posY) {
                case "middle":
                    this.posY = (cnv.height - this.height) / 2;
                    break;
                case "top":
                    this.posY = 0;
                    break;
                case "bottom":
                    this.posY = cnv.height - this.height;
                    break;
            }
            ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.srcX * this.width, this.srcY * this.height, this.width, this.height, this.posX, this.posY, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    halfHeight () {
        return this.height / 2;
    }
    halfWidth () {
        return this.width / 2;
    }
    rightEdge () {
        return this.posX + this.width;
    }
    stop (direction) {
        if (this.walking == direction) {
            this.walking = null;
        }
    }
    walk () {
        if (!this.acting && this.walking) {
            switch (this.walking) {
                case "left":
                    this.animate(9, 9);
                    this.posX -= this.speed;
                    break;
                case "right":
                    this.animate(11, 9);
                    this.posX += this.speed;
                    break;
                case "up":
                    this.animate(8, 9);
                    this.posY -= this.speed;
                    break;
                case "down":
                    this.animate(10, 9);
                    this.posY += this.speed;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4. `js/collision.js`:

```js
function action (a, b) {
    switch (a.action()) {
        case "shoot":
            shoot(a, b);
            break;
        case "thrust":
        case "slash":
            attack(a, b);
            break;
    }
}
function collision (a, b) {
    var x = Math.abs(a.centerX() - b.centerX());
    var y = Math.abs(a.centerY() - b.centerY());
    var width = a.halfWidth() + b.halfWidth();
    var height = a.halfHeight() + b.halfHeight();
    if (x < width && y < height && b.visible) {
        switch (a.direction()) {
            case "up":
                a.posY += height - y;
                break;
            case "left":
                a.posX += width - x;
                break;
            case "down":
                a.posY -= height - y;
                break;
            case "right":
                a.posX -= width - x;
                break;
        }
    }
}
function shoot (a, b) {
    switch (a.direction()) {
        case "up":
            if (a.centerX() > b.posX && a.centerX() < b.rightEdge() && a.posY > b.posY) {
                b.visible = false;
            }
            break;
        case "left":
            if (a.centerY() > b.posY && a.centerY() < b.bottomEdge() && a.posX > b.posX) {
                b.visible = false;
            }
            break;
        case "down":
            if (a.centerX() > b.posX && a.centerX() < b.rightEdge() && a.posY < b.posY) {
                b.visible = false;
            }
            break;
        case "right":
            if (a.centerY() > b.posY && a.centerY() < b.bottomEdge() && a.posX < b.posX) {
                b.visible = false;
            }
            break;
    }
}
function attack (c, d) {
    var x = Math.abs(c.centerX() - d.centerX());
    alert(x);
    var y = Math.abs(c.centerY() - d.centerY());
    var width = c.halfWidth() + d.halfWidth();
    var height = c.halfHeight() + d.halfHeight();
    switch (c.direction()) {
        case "up":
            if (x <= width && y <= height && c.posY > d.posY) {
                d.visible = false;
            }
            break;
        case "left":
            if (x <= width && y <= height && c.posX > d.posX) {
                d.visible = false;
            }
            break;
        case "down":
            if (x <= width && y <= height && c.posY < d.posY) {
                d.visible = false;
            }
            break;
        case "right":
            if (x <= width && y <= height && c.posX < d.posX) {
                d.visible = false;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

5. `js/load.js`:

```js
//carrega javascript
function loadJS () {
    for (var i in arguments) {
        document.write("<script src='" + arguments[i] + ".js'></script>");
    }
}
//carrega imagens
function loadImgs () {
    var imgs = new Object();
    for (var i in arguments) {
        var start = arguments[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
        var end = arguments[i].indexOf(".");
        var name = arguments[i].substring(start, end);
        imgs[name] = new Image();
        imgs[name].src = arguments[i];
    }
    return imgs;
}
```

6. `js/message.js`:

```js
class Message {
    constructor (text, x, y, font, color, visible) {
        //propriedades
        this.text = text;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.font = font;
        this.color = color;
        this.visible = visible;
    }
    //metodos
    fillText (cnv, ctx) {
        if (this.visible) { 
            ctx.font = this.font;
            switch (this.x) {
                case "center":
                    this.x = (cnv.width - ctx.measureText(this.text).width) / 2;
                    break;
                case "left":
                    this.x = 0;
                    break;
                case "right":
                    this.x = cnv.width - ctx.measureText(this.text).width;
                    break;
            }
            switch (this.y) {
                case "middle":
                    this.y = (cnv.height - parseInt(this.font)) / 2;
                    break;
                case "top":
                    this.y = 0;
                    break;
                case "bottom":
                    this.y = cnv.height - parseInt(this.font);
                    break;
            }
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y, cnv.width);
        }
    }
}
```

7. `js/script.js`:

```js
//carrega as imagens
var imgs = loadImgs("img/character/princess.png", "img/character/skeleton.png", "img/character/soldier.png");
//onload
onload = function () {
    //variaveis
    var cnv = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    var msgs = [];
    var chars = [];
    var status = "start";
    //cria as mensagens
    msgs["title"] = new Message("UNDIVINE", "center", "middle", "80px 'Alfa Slab One'", "#fff", true);
    //cria os personagens
    chars["player"] = new Character(imgs["princess"], "left", "middle", false);
    chars["skeleton"] = new Character(imgs["skeleton"], "center", "middle", false);
    chars["soldier"] = new Character(imgs["soldier"], "right", "middle", false);
    //eventos
    cnv.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (status == "start") {
            msgs["title"].visible = false;
            for (var i in chars) {
                chars[i].visible = true;
            }
            status = "play";
        }
    }, false);
    addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        if (status == "play") {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 37:
                    chars["player"].walking = "left";
                    break;
                case 38:
                    chars["player"].walking = "up";
                    break;
                case 39:
                    chars["player"].walking = "right";
                    break;
                case 40:
                    chars["player"].walking = "down";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, false);
    addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
        if (status == "play") {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 37:
                    chars["player"].stop("left");
                    break;
                case 38:
                    chars["player"].stop("up");
                    break;
                case 39:
                    chars["player"].stop("right");
                    break;
                case 40:
                    chars["player"].stop("down");
                    break;
                case 88:
                    chars["player"].acting = "slash";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, false);
    //funcoes
    function loop () {
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        if (status == "play") {
            update();
        }
        render();
    }
    function update () {
        for (var i in chars) {
            chars[i].walk();
            for (var j in chars) {
                if (i != j) {
                    collision(chars[i], chars[j]);
                    action(chars[i], chars[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function render () {
        //limpa o canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
        //desenha os personagens
        for (var i in chars) {
            chars[i].draw(cnv, ctx);
        }
        //escreve as mensagens
        for (var i in msgs) {
            msgs[i].fillText(cnv, ctx);
        }
    }
    //inicia as funcoes
    loop();
}
```

8. `img/character/princess.png`:

[image: princess.png]

9. `img/character/skeleton.png`:

[image: skeleton.png]

10. `img/character/soldier.png`:

[image: soldier.png]

Ou, se quiser baixar tudo do Google Drive, a URL é https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7nZsfA3eMi9NHpjQ3FIRTlybFk?usp=sharing

Comment: O que é e como está declarado `chars`? Quais são as funções `collision` e `action`? Onde e como está declarado o método `walk`?

Comment: Irei editar a pergunta.

Comment: Se quiser eu posso upar os arquivos pro google drive, é bem leve, ainda tá 
bem no começo.

Comment: Explica melhor qual é a "forma inesperada". E qual é a primeira vez? Pelo código que você colocou no drive, isso está dentro de um loop infinito, com requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: O inesperado é que quando teclo x ele ataca com a lanca e quando termina deve detectar se atingiu o alvo mas na primeira vez ele detecta como nao atingiu, e na segunda ele detecta que atingiu.